# Add row when checkbox checked virtual cxgrid delphi

Tags: delphi

I need help! 
I created a (non-binding) on my virtual cxgrid chekbox field, now when the User clicks, I want to check if it is checked and get the value from column 2 of the same line checked. I want to make a counter if checked. I Use Delphi 7 + cxGrid Dev Express.
Thank you, 
Clayton

Comment: I'm not too sure people will understand what you're asking for.  What do you mean by the word "checked" in "and get the value from column 2 of the same line checked" and in "I want to make a counter if checked." - sounds like you want to increment a counter, but which "checked" are you talking about?

Comment: cxGrid comes with extensive set of examples. Your question is messy and it is hard to catch general idea, but all parts of question sound trivial. Check doks/exmaples first and try to ask specific question. BTW DevExpress provides great support for customers.